# How can I listen to free online music while performing other tasks on my device?

Tags: music, htc-desire-z

I have Android 2.2 on my phone and I want an app that lets me listen to free music online in the background while I browse through other apps or do something else on my phone.
The YouTube app closes once I minimize it, so I have to keep it open to listen to music.
I have tried apps like Shazam and Soundhound but they don't offer free music. Can anyone recommend a good app?

Comment: i have tried out grooveshark but that app is only for a 30 month trial.

Comment: I have found YouTube music beta. it is pretty nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heart Radio and TuneIn Radio are apps that let you stream FM radio stations.  You select the sort of station you like and listen to the music they play.

I personally use them for listening to talk radio, but same difference.

Answer (score 3):

Depending which country you're in [Last.fm](https://market.android.com/details?id=fm.last.android) and [Spotify](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spotify.mobile.android.ui) are good options for free, streaming music.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your own music collection, you can get a [Google Music](https://music.google.com) account, download the [app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.music) if it isn't already on your phone, and listen to your own tunes all you like.

If you're looking for an internet radio app, I'd recommend [Slacker Radio](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.slacker.radio&hl=en), they have a lot of channels with pretty decent selection.  [Pandora](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pandora.android) is very good, but that only works if you live in the United States.

Comment: is google music free?

Comment: Yes, although they're happy to sell you songs.